# masterPage help me

Tags: master-pages, pageload

I have one MasterPage and 2 pages(Home.aspx and LogIn.aspx).

I set as StartPage the Home.aspx.

When i begin the project the debugger first passes by the Page_Load(Home.aspx) and after Page_Load(MasterPage). Very nice!!!

when i click the LogIn.aspx link by menu(in masterPage) the debugger first passes by **AGAIN FROM THE Page_Load(Home.aspx) .......WHY??????????** (...after masterPage after Login.aspx and finally again from MasterPage.....)

Is there any solution when i click the LogIn link to pass by Login.aspx Page_Load method and finally masterPage Page_Load method???

pls help me!!!

All pages are empty(simple).. neither img nor src...

Comment: You really need to show us your code as it's not clear what the "Login.aspx link by menu" is, which makes it nearly impossible to provide you with help

Comment: thnx rob i find it...

Answer (score 0):

the problem was that the LogIn link was asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtnLogIn" runat="server" OnClick="lnkBtnLogIn_Click">LogIn

I replaced with a ID="lnkBtnLogIn" href="/Pages/LogIn.aspx">LogIn